# How to automatically load files on a website

Tags: html, ftp, web

Hello guys,

I just got into web programming, learned a bit on codecademy and i bought a domain: sanruza.com

I created basic.html and wanted to test it. It works but how do i make it load automatically?
I tried googling the question but i don't even know how to phrase it... 
Can anyone give me some basic tips/steps.
Thank you for your time and again sorry for bothering with such a basic question...

Here's what i'm loading. It has no problem loading it after i click it

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>
         A Small Hello 
      </TITLE>
   </HEAD>
<BODY>
   <H1>Hi</H1>
   <P>This is very minimal "hello world" HTML document.</P> 
</BODY>
```

Comment: Renaming to index.html should wrok...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name the file index.html instead of basic.html. Web server always looks for index file first.

Comment: I thought about mentioning it, but I didn't want to complicate things. The rest of the behavior is also depends on server configuration, for example, the priority of extensions (html, php), auto generated index of content.

Answer (score 2):

rename it to index.html that should make it open directly when you go to sanruza.com(assuming it's on the server there)